# add a space infront of capitals?

Tags: c

How do i add a space in front of capital letters in a string?

I am writing a c code for school that requires a function that adds a space in front of every capital letter in a concantenated sentence

e.g.
"HelloHowAreYou"
should look like
Hello How Are you

this what I have tried and as far as I got

```
int i;

i = 1;

  while (str[i] != '\0')

 {

   if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')

   i = i + 1;
 }
```

can anyone help?

Comment: `i` should start at `0`. And when a char is found that is not a capital letter, this loop becomes an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

To see why this wouldn't work try running your code with a pencil on a piece of paper. When you see a capital letter, all you do is skipping the index. Moreover, you never do any copying (and you do need to copy, because the letters after the capital ones need to move).

To figure out what to do, think of doing the move from the back: walk the indexes down from the end, inserting a space *after* each capital letter that you encounter.

There is only one wrinkle to this - knowing where the updated string ends. That's easy to compute, though, if you add the number of capital letters to the length of the string.

Of course you need to be sure that the updated string is going to fit in the space of the old string.

```
char str[100];
scanf("%50s", str);
int len = strlen(str);
if (len == 0) return; // Stop if the string is empty.
for (int i = 1 ; str[i] != '\0' ; i++) {
    if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
        len++;
}
int pos = strlen(str);
while (pos > 0) {
    str[len] = str[pos--];
    if (str[len] >= 'A' && str[len] <= 'Z') {
        str[--len] = ' ';
    }
    len--;
}
printf("%s\n", str);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/uIl8IE)

Comment: dasblinkenlight, i got your code to work, thanks, but it seems to double the 2nd letter of the string each time

Comment: If the capital letter is at the first position it should not be counted to the new length of string: `if ((str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') && (i > 0) )   len++;`

Comment: Or use `for (int i = 1 ; str[i] != '\0' ; i++) {` instead of `for (int i = 0 ; str[i] != '\0' ; i++) {`

Comment: anto, this added a space at the beginning, but worked with a 2 word string, more than two words though and it added random characters at the end

Comment: @vince You are welcome! If this helps you solve the problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This would earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow, and let other site visitors know that you are not actively looking for a better solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *
addspaces (const char *src)
{
  /* first find the length of the required string */
  int l = 1;                    /* to allow for terminating NUL */
  const char *s;
  char *dest;
  char *d;

  for (s = src; *s; s++, l++)
    if (isupper (*s))
      l++;

  /* now allocate memory for the string */
  dest = malloc (l);
  if (!dest)
    return NULL;

  /* now copy the original string into the buffer */
  for (s = src, d = dest; *s;)
    {
      if (isupper (*s))
        *d++ = ' ';
      *d++ = *s++;
    }
  *d = 0;
  return dest;
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *test = "AddSpacesToThisString";
  char *out = addspaces (test);
  printf ("Result: %s\n", out);
  free (out);
  exit (0);
}
```

You can see it working here: http://ideone.com/eKMIV0

This has the advantage of dynamically allocating the return buffer, rather than relying on a fixed length string.

Comment: Abligh, although im sure this works, i believe this is above our scope of knowledge currently